# Replacing keys by values according to some predefined object in javascript

Tags: arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular7

I have an object having key-value pairs. Another array has only a partial set of keys. I want a third array that contains only values and that too only for those keys which are present in the second array.

```
let x= {'Hello':'Monday', 'World':'Tuesday', 'Program':'Wednesday'}
let y = ['Program','Hello']
```

What I require in output is :
`y=['Wednesday', 'Monday']`

Comment: Is anything stopping you from achieving what you require? Please note that SO is not a **get code for free** site. We solve problems of our fellow developers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
let x= {'Hello':'Monday', 'World':'Tuesday', 'Program':'Wednesday'}
let y = ['Program','Hello']

console.log(y.map(val => x[val]));
```

Comment: Please add explanation. Just code is incomplete answer

Comment: code was quite obvious. So didn't feel a need of explanation. Its just a map function of array.

Comment: If it was that obvious, OP would have not asked. Remember, you are answering for readers and they have all levels. So its always better to explain what and why.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make sure that the result contains only existing values. If so, you need to loop through `y` values and make sure the `x` object has a such property.

```js
let x = {'Hello': 'Monday', 'World': 'Tuesday', 'Program': 'Wednesday'},
    y = ['Program', 'Hello', 'Test'],
    z = [];

for (let prop of y) {
  if (prop in x) {
    z.push(x[prop]);
  }
}

console.log(z);
```